# facebook Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone say if following the instructions in the section entitled as per above in

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

allows long lived access tokens to be refreshed daily?
For the last two months, I've been generating a new long lived token each day, but today I got an expiration error message. I am definitely generating a new token each day, but does this token expire 60 days from its creation?

Many thanks

Comment: Why would you create a new long-lived token every day? With a long-lived one, you get around 60 days of validity – so work with that, and renew it when it is _close_ to expiring.

Comment: And what you are asking in the question title definitively makes no sense at all. You can not create long-lived tokens from already long-lived tokens – only from a short-lived token.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way round this.
In response to your questions:
(a) I have a script that runs daily and that makes calls to the Facebook API. The reason why I want to create a new long lived token each day is because I do not want to keep track and see if I am near expiry
(b) It is possible to create a long lived token from a long lived token as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code under the section 'Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens'